# My bot is always sending the same random message (as an interaction)

Tags: discord.js

I'm more or less new to coding, and I'm trying to code a bot by myself, to play Rock, Paper Scissors.

This RPS game works with Discord buttons, when you click on one of the 3 buttons, the bot randomly replies with one of the 3 different options.

I tested the bot, and everything works fine, except for the random reply. My bot sends one of the 3 options, but until I restart it through the console, it will always send the same option no matter which utton I click.

Here is the part of the code where the options are defined, as well as the interaction:

````
const emoji = [
    "✊", 
    "✋", 
    "✌"
];

const randomemoji = emoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * emoji.length)];

client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    if(interaction.isButton()){
    if(interaction.customId === "Pierre" || "Papier" || "Ciseaux"){
       await interaction.reply(randomemoji);
    }```

What could I do to make my bot not send the same emoji every time, without restarting it every time?

Thanks in advance !
````

Comment: Hi, currently you create a random emoji and send it when the button is clicked. What you need to do is: when the button is clicked, generate a random emoji and send it. move the `const randomemoji = emoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * emoji.length)];` line before `await interaction.reply(randomemoji);` so that both are inside the if block

Comment: Just tried that and it works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a random emoji inside your event listener.
Your code should look something like this:

```
const emoji = [
  "✊", 
  "✋", 
  "✌"
];

client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
  if(interaction.isButton()){
  if(interaction.customId === "Pierre" || "Papier" || "Ciseaux"){
     const randomEmoji = emoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * emoji.length)];
     await interaction.reply(randomEmoji);
}
```